# Javascript, get all links from a page with exclusion?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I want to get all links `<a></a>` from a page and got this code that is working without any problem:

```
var array = [];
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0, max=links.length; i<max; i++) {
    array.push(links[i].href);
};
console.table(array);
```

Only thing left I would like to add here is some code to exclude links that have for example "google" or something in it, but I dont know how to do that (newbie in Javascript).

Hope someone can help me here, thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (!links[i].href.includes('google')) array.push(links[i].href);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some code to exclude links that have for example "google" or something

You need to add if condition and check with `includes` method

```
var array = [];
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0, max=links.length; i<max; i++) {
    let link = links[i].href;
    if(link.includes('google')==false) // if(!link.includes('google'))
        array.push(link);
};
console.table(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but `getElementsByTagName`  returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not an array. Fortunately there's a simple way to pretend it's an array and use the `filter` function - `[].filter.call(htmlCollection, filterFunc)`.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var array = [].filter.call(links, link => !link.href.toLowerCase().includes('google'))
  .map(link => link.href);
  
console.log(array);
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="https://oracle.com">Oracle</a>
<a href="https://microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems a little cleaner chaining the array functions.